# Why is looping through an array several times faster the second time around in Go?

Tags: go

This is a simple script that just filters out certain characters.

I was comparing the regex version to the array version and found enormous speed improvements, but I noticed that doing the same array statement again increases the speed several-fold. I'm re-initializing all the variables - I think - so I'm trying to understand why this is happening.

```
func checkFormat(s string) (bool, string) {

    const allowedCharacters = "abcdefghijkklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890-"
    var reg, _ = regexp.Compile("[^A-Za-z0-9-]+")

    start := time.Now()
    filteredRegex := reg.ReplaceAllString(s, "")
    end := time.Since(start)
    fmt.Println("REGEX: ", end)

    start = time.Now()
    equalsArray := make([]rune, len(s))
    removed := 0
    for i, r := range s {
        if (r >= 97 && r <= 122) || (r >= 65 && r <= 90) || (r >= 48 && r <= 57) || r == 45 {
            equalsArray[i-removed] = r
        } else {
            removed++
        }
    }
    end = time.Since(start)
    fmt.Println("FIRST: ", end)

    start = time.Now()
    equalsArrayx := make([]rune, len(s))
    removedx := 0
    for i, r := range s {
        if (r >= 97 && r <= 122) || (r >= 65 && r <= 90) || (r >= 48 && r <= 57) || r == 45 {
            equalsArrayx[i-removedx] = r
        } else {
            removedx++
        }
    }
    end = time.Since(start)
    fmt.Println("SECOND: ", end)

    if filteredRegex == s {
        return true, filteredRegex
    } else {
        return false, filteredRegex
    }
}
```

Output:

```
REGEX:  23.917µs
FIRST:  3.208µs
SECOND:  708ns
```

Comment: My first guess is that the compiler is smart enough to re-use the memory for the first slice, so it doesn't have to allocate again. You can test this by [inspecting the assembly](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/objdump) or starting to measure after the slice declaration. However, benchmarks like this are inherently unreliable. With a single execution there is just too much potential for noise to yield meaningful results.

Comment: Or because the array is loaded in the CPU cache on the second loop.

Comment: Modern computers (i.e. microcode, cores, cpas, caches, memory) are incredible complicated and reasoning about them is _unbelivable_ hard. Guess: Less memory access (which is slow) in the second run.